# how to show firebase rumtime database data in html table

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show my listed data from fire base database to table
i did that code

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var ref = firebase.database().ref('customer');

ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to loop over the items coming from the database and write HTML content via javascript:

```
var myTable = "<table border='1' width='100%'><tr>";

ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var item = childSnapshot.val();
        var firstName = childSnapshot.val().firstName   //Example of value
        myTable += "<td align='center'>" + firstName + "</td>";
    });
});

myTable += "</tr></table>";

document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = myTable;
```

However it would be better to use a JS framework to "inject" your data from JavaScript to your HTML DOM, i.e. Vue.js or Knockout, just to mention two examples.